# How to keep an OSM routing topology updated?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I have a South America import and an `osm2po` topology table. My database is updated daily using osmosis but how to keep the topology table updated without make all import over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even small changes force a complete rebuild of the osm2po topology. The reason are the OSM-IDs which change with each new delta.

Comment: Seriously? I thought this never changed.

Comment: Of course, only when sth. changes. But then everything can happen. Imagine someone adds a new node C between A and B. Then deletes B and moves C to Bs position. And there are more examples.

Comment: Makes sense. This is bad! Rebuild all topology at every planet update is impossible. What can I do?